# A questions concerning Laguerre/Voronoi tessellations

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

Fix $n>1$ distinguished points $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in \mathbb R^d$, the **Voronoi tessellations** are the subsets $V_1,\ldots V_n\subset\mathbb R^d$ defined by

$$V_k~~ := ~~ \big\{x\in\mathbb R^d:\quad |x-x_k|^2~\le ~ |x-x_i|^2,~  \mbox{ for all } i=1,\ldots, n\big\}.$$

Next we introduce $n$ *translation parameters* $c_1,\ldots, c_n\in (-\infty,\infty)$, then the **Laguerre tessellations** are given by, with $C:=(c_1,\ldots, c_n)\in\mathbb R^n$,

$$L_k(C)~~ := ~~ \big\{x\in\mathbb R^d:\quad |x-x_k|^2-c_k~\le ~ |x-x_i|^2-c_i,~  \mbox{ for all } i=1,\ldots, n\big\}.$$

Assume we are given a smooth density function $\rho:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R_+$, and discrete probability weights $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\subset (0,1)$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i=1$, my question is how to find  $C\in\mathbb R^n$ s.t.

$$\int_{L_i(C)}\rho(x)dx=\alpha_i,~ \mbox{ for all } i=1,\ldots, n.$$

The problem arises in my research, and I am interested in the computation of $\nabla_{x_i}c_k$. I have tried with some particular cases, i.e. $d=1$ or $n=2$, where some concrete analysis can be carried out. But for general $d$ and $n$, I have no idea whether there is some related literature. Any solution or reference will highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following two articles might be helpful:

*Aurenhammer, F.; Hoffmann, F.; Aronov, B.*, [**Minkowski-type theorems and least-squares clustering**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/PL00009187), Algorithmica 20, No. 1, 61-76 (1998). [ZBL0895.68135](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0895.68135).

*Gu, Xianfeng; Luo, Feng; Sun, Jian; Yau, Shing-Tung*, [**Variational principles for Minkowski type problems, discrete optimal transport, and discrete Monge-Ampère equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/AJM.2016.v20.n2.a7), Asian J. Math. 20, No. 2, 383-398 (2016). [ZBL1339.49039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1339.49039).